# Algebraically prove minimum for $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-x^Tb$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I need to algebraically prove minimum for $\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-x^Tb$ using $r = A^{-1}x-b.$

I can write $x$ as $A(r+b)$ and whole expression as 
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &=\frac{1}{2}(r+b)^TA^3(r+b) - (r+b)^TAb \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(Ar)^TA(Ar) - (Ar)^Tb \\
& + \frac{1}{2}(Ab)^TA(Ab) - (Ab)^Tb \\
& + (Ar)^TA^2b \\
\end{align}
$$

And i don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a strange substitution. Try instead with $x=A^{-1} b + r$

Comment: OMH, i spent nearly two hours fighting it! What a waste! Thanks a lot.